# How can I push my Home button to the top left of my header in CSS?

Tags: html, css

```
`<header>
   <img src="images/chefs-hat.png">
   <p>Popular Recipes</p>
   <button class="home">
   <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   </button>    
 </header>



.home {
   width: 100px;
   text-decoration: none;
   float: left;
   display: block;
  font-size: 20px; 
 }`
```

html/Css home(a) section. Wondering how to push this element to the top-left of my header.

Comment: Post your html code?

Comment: Please read how to post a question with relevant code. Not much to go with here.

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's rather difficult to answer this question without it. It would help if you could update your question to list all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example if you want us to help

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write your home button at the top of the container? Why do you need `float: left`? You have to explain it, otherwise I consider it to be not essential.

```css
.home {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.home a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <button class="home">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </button>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="placeholder" />
  <p>Popular Recipes</p>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS. More info on absolute positioning here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

```
header {
  position: relative;
}

.home {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px; 
}
```

Comment: I am brand new with not enough reputation to vote, or else I would. It says it was recorded though.